# how can i store the values i give in html label in to a javascript array and set values for each array element?

Tags: html

```
<optgroup label="BEVERAGES">
    <option value="1">milo</option>
    <option value="2">milk</option>
    <option value="3">golden morn</option>
    <option value="4">nescafe</option>
    <option value="5">coffee</option>
</optgroup>
```

in the code above, i want to set the values of every beverage item to have individual prices

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Javascript (as in the question) rather than just setting the value attributes correctly in the source HTML? We really need to know what you're trying to achieve in order to be helpful!

Comment: yes, i already set the values, so it will be possible to reference the value in the javascript array and give each value a preset default price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <select name="yourname" id="yourid" onChange="setter(this);">
        <optgroup label="BEVERAGES">
            <option value="1">milo</option>
            <option value="2">milk</option>
            <option value="3">golden morn</option>
            <option value="4">nescafe</option>
            <option value="5">coffee</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
<script>
    function setter(selectBox) {
        var op = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
        var optgroup = op.parentNode;
        alert("selected option text is:  " + op.text + " \noptGroup label is:  " + optgroup.label);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only sent an alert message to the window. How can i give each item a price value, such that on click of the item,it shows a price value